# Typeform Responses API - excluded_response_id flag

Tags: python, api, sdk, typeform

The [documentation](https://developer.typeform.com/responses/reference/retrieve-responses/) mentions an `excluded_response_id` field but the param doesn't seem to be available. In fact it's not showing [here](https://github.com/Typeform/typeform-python-sdk/blob/78816908f1b7bcc25ee473afc7ed81005a13d68f/typeform/responses.py#L26).

My use case is to retrieve only the responses that I have not seen yet (aka new responses) and this flag makes perfect sense.

For example:

```
self.typeform.responses.list(form_id, excludedResponseIds=["<id>",])
```

The response I get back is

```
TypeError: list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'excludedResponseIds'
```